# Device File Explorer missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm a beginner developer and I use flutter, I wanted to download databases inside my app in the emulator within Android Studio.
But no matter where I search, I can't find the Device File Explorer in the android studio, the only thing I find about it is in settings and it's a completely blank page (there is only the path where to download things).

[image: This is well usually people tell me to go]

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Device File Explorer option missing in Flutter Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608762/device-file-explorer-option-missing-in-flutter-android-studio)

Comment: Already tried those solutions and doesn't work. No framework is been detected in my event log.

Answer (score 18):

For Normal Android Development, it's easy. Just go to

> ```
> View -> Tool Windows -> Device Manager
> ```

But in Flutter Development, it's a little bit tricky.

First you have to Configure your Android Development with `Flutter` to see the `Device Manager` option.

**Steps:**
Click on the bottom right option where it says `Event Log` and then Press `Configure Now`
**Done!**

No go to the same path again which was

> ```
> View -> Tool Windows
> ```

and here you can see the `Device Manager` is visible now.
[image: Event Log]

Comment: Hello! I tried that but I cannot see anything saying "configure now" (before and after emulator is running the app).

the only notification I see is:
"Unsupported Android Studio version: Canary versions of Android Studio are not supported by the Flutter plugin."

I wonder if that is the source of my problems!

(nb. I also usually read "Unable to located adb", but emulator runs great after that. So I ignored this issue, since all common solutions didn't also really worked)

Comment: Well i was getting 
(Frameworks Detected->
    Android framework is detected. ->
    and then "Configure") and i clicked configure and it was all done.

Comment: Oh ok, I don't get that. I'll try installing a NON-Canary version of AS

Comment: Ok that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: This does work for me. Not sure why some are not seeing it.

Comment: in mine android studio, bottom right options are missing like you have the device file explorer. Previously it has Emulator option as well but now they are gone !

Answer (score -5):

You can just use your real device to test and It will be better.

1. Just connect your mobile with usb to your computer.
2. turn on USB debugging in developer mode.
3. you will see a dialog box in mobile just allow and you are ready to use it.

Hope it will be helpful I suggest it coz once when I was trying my app in emulator it was working fine but when I have tested it on real device many things were not working and I have to start my project from scratch. So I suggest to test on real device and in addition you will easily get file explorer and more.

Comment: He can't use just a real device. Please just focus on what asked. I have the same trouble and I need to see all device files without root permission. On my real device i can't do it without root so I have to do this through emulator..